# Algorithm to test a graph for $t$-transitivity

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am looking for an algorithm, which given a graph $G$ and a natural number $t$, determines if $G$ is [$t$-transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_graph).

I am also interested in knowing if this problem is in P, NP, NPC or some other interesting facts about its complexity class.

Answer (score 4):

If you had an oracle from Graph Isomorphism, then for constant $t$ you can check whether a graph is $t$-transitive. For example, to check if a graph is $1$-transitive, for every vertex $i$ create a variant $G_i$ of your original graph by attaching an "appendage" at vertex $i$, say a very long path or a very large star. The graph is transitive if all $G_i,G_j$ are isomorphic.